# Unidentified Index/Illegal String Offset

Tags: php, string, web, content-management-system

First of all I apologise is the question title doesn't explain much, I am new to PHP and find it hard to word the question as I'm not even really sure what is wrong.

Here is the PHP

```
    <?php
    include 'includes/connection.php';

    $pName = $_POST['pName'];
    $pAuth = $_POST['pAuth'];
    $pCon = $_POST['pCon'];
    $Page = $_POST['Page'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $update = "UPDATE content SET POST_TITLE = '$pname(pname)',POST_AUTHOR = '$pauth(pauth)',POST_CONTENT = '$pcon(pcon)',PAGE = '$page(page) WHERE ID = '$id[id]'";

    $result = mysql_query($update) or die (mysql_error());

    Header("Location:admin.php?refer=editsuccess");
?>
```

and the error,

```
Notice: Undefined index: pauth in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\editp.php on line 5

Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\editp.php on line 10
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: What you're doing is incredibly insecure.  You are **wide open** to SQL injection and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to use prepared queries with PDO or similar, and avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: Thank you for the advice I will do that from now on, I am using a tutorial to create a simple CMS, I thought if I do that, it is a good way to learn PHP/MySQL. I'll look up prepared queries.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things to note here.

You are receiving the warnings and notices because of the way you're trying to interpolate your variables into your query string.  You start out by pulling variables out of $_POST and into local variables.  However, instead of using those variables, you're attempting to access them as if they were functions and arrays.  It's also important to remember that variable names in PHP are case sensitive.  You're also missing a quote or two.

The query should look more like this:

`$update = "UPDATE content SET POST_TITLE = '$pName', POST_AUTHOR = '$pAuth', POST_CONTENT = '$pCon', PAGE = '$Page' WHERE ID = '$id'";`

That being said, this query is inherently insecure, because a user could quite easily [alter your query](http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/tutorial/SQLInjection/index.htm) and do a variety of harmful things to your database.

The `mysql_` functions are considered to be unsafe and outdated, so you can solve the problem relating to SQL injection by replacing them with one of two more modern mysql wrappers: [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: You can't simply solve the SQL injection problem by using a new wrapper.  You must use prepared queries as well, and be diligent about how you structure your application.

Answer (score 1):

I think your mysql query should be like:

```
$update = "UPDATE content SET POST_TITLE = '$pname',POST_AUTHOR = '$pauth',POST_CONTENT = '$pcon',PAGE = '$page' WHERE ID = '$id'";
```

Comment: That's worked and I'll use the advice you have all given me. Thanks pal!

Comment: This is open to SQL injection.  At least escape your input!